# XPEnology phpMyAdmin cannot log in to mysql

Tags: synology

Installed XPEnology operating system, and using package manager installed MariaDB and phpMyAdmin.

Tired to login to phpMyAdmin http://WEB/phpMyAdmin and receiving a 'Cannot connect to local server' error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the control panel enable SSH.
2. Login to SSH using Putty (http://www.putty.org), using the username and password you originally set up the XPEnology with.
3. Issue this command, changing the *** to your password

mysqladmin -u root password *******

4. You should now be able to login to phpMyAdmin on Synology. Username should be 'root'